# Julia DifferentialEquation package stopped working after update

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I added the Vega package and tried rerunning some DiffEq code and am now getting the following

```
[ Info: Precompiling DifferentialEquations [0c46a032-eb83-5123-abaf-
570d42b7fbaa]
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: @pack not defined
```

With a lot of subpackages inside DiffEq failing to precompile. I have removed both Vega and DiffEq and reinstalled DiffEq but I still have the same error.

I am currently running Julia 0.7.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a one day thing (September 4th, 2018) because of an non-deprecated breaking change in Parameters.jl. If you just update your packages this will go away. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Yeah. Should I go ahead and delete this question?

Comment: It's probably a good idea since this is now no longer relevant to readers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues/342

Pinning an older version of Parameters resolved the issue for now.